# Room TypeConverter transform multiple DB columns into one field?

Tags: android, android-room, android-database

Is there a way to have one Room TypeConverter that will take multiple table fields and combine them into some object?

As an example, let's assume I have a table Foo that has columns `INT numerator`, `INT denominator` (together representing a fraction), and `INT unit` (unit maps to an enum of measurement units). I want to combine them into `MyScalar(Fraction(numerator, denominator), unit)`. For example, possibly take a row `(1, 5, 2)` (where the `2` maps to `MeasurementUnit.KG`) and use a `@TypeConverter` to turn this row into `MyScalar(Fraction(1,5), MeasurementUnit.KG)`.

Right now I'm just doing

```
data class MyEntity(
    val numerator: Int, 

    val denominator: Int, 

    @TypeConverters(IntAndUnitConverter::class) 
    val unit: MeasurementUnit
) {
    fun combine(): MyScalar {
        return MyScalar(Fraction(numerator, denominator), unit)
    }
}
```

with

```
data class MyScalar(val value: Fraction, val unit: MeasurementUnit)
```

Seems to do the trick, but I find the idea appealing of just having my @Entity have @TypeConverters(SomeThreeColumnConverter::class) up top and not worry about remembering to invoke combine() or anything like that.

I don't think it's possible, but wanted to check.